# Styling of Buttons is being overwritten

Tags: css, javafx, styling, scenebuilder

this is my first post.
I searched for the problem but I couldn't find any solution.

I work with JavaFX, Scenebuilder and CSS files, where I have 2 Buttons and Textfields and other stuff, that are given style classes.

However, when displaying the view, the button styles are being overwritten.
Everything else gets displayed properly but not the buttons.
I can't explain that to myself, however, I have added random buttons and they get overwritten aswell. So I know that somewhere is said that all buttons receive this certain style.

This is a group project, so not all of the code is written by me.
Is there a method in JavaFX that sets styles for certain element types i.e. buttons without styling a specific button? I suspect that this is being done somewhere or maybe the view is inheriting said styling from some other view, because in our project we load stages into each other.
Say I can't fix the occasions where style overriding happens. Is there  a way to protect these two specific buttons or buttons in general from getting their style classes overwritten?

OT: why is "hello there" in the beginning of the post being cut out.

Comment: Can you post some code to show what you have done?

Comment: You should [edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete and Verifiable example](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly, I think I have found the problem. In our Rootlayout, there is an Id :controls, which is inherited all the way to the bottom, and this with in conjunciton with our css file, makes it so the buttons are styled the way they are. I just need to override this default inherited styling for buttons